# How do I host a website that depends on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hosting, serverside-javascript

When running the site locally, I include all my node files in the same folder as the index.html file and then from the console I run the server side js which is node-dependent.

So in hosting this online, do I upload all the node files into the website directory? and how do I run the serverside js once the website is ready to be run?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a hosting service that supports node.js. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/home) is a good option for starting out. They have a free tier available. Once you have signed up, setting up your site and deploying it is quite simple if you're using a git repository and their [command-line tools](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).